# How do i solve this kubernetes pod error that keeps runnning into CreateContainerConfigError state

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks, kubernetes-secrets

I get this error each time I try to install a helm chart on azure kubernetes service. Initially I got this error:

````
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  44s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned xxx/xxx-cdn-864bb-sz8p to aks-2810-vmss00001y
  Normal   Pulled     43s               kubelet            Container image "df3.azurecr.io/cist/cist-istio-proxyv2:1.16.3" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    43s               kubelet            Created container istio-init
  Normal   Started    43s               kubelet            Started container istio-init
  Normal   Pulled     42s               kubelet            Container image "ncdaksbsztankosdwdbdf3.azurecr.io/cist/cist-istio-proxyv2:1.16.3" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    42s               kubelet            Created container istio-proxy
  Normal   Started    42s               kubelet            Started container istio-proxy
  Normal   Pulling    42s               kubelet            Pulling image "df3.azurecr.io/xxx-engine:23.6.0-123.gf12345"
  Normal   Pulled     30s               kubelet            Successfully pulled image "df3.azurecr.io/xxx-engine:23.6.0-123.gf12345" in 11.461509574s
  Warning  Failed     2s (x6 over 30s)  kubelet            Error: couldn't find key CDS_TOKEN in Secret cds/cds-token
  Normal   Pulled     2s (x5 over 29s)  kubelet            Container image "df3.azurecr.io/cds-engine:23.6.0-562.gf195010" already present on machine ```

i then created the secret but now get this.
````

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  29m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned xxx/xxx-hooks-1234xl2 to aks-ncd-2810-vmss1q
  Warning  Failed     27m (x12 over 29m)     kubelet            Error: couldn't find key XXX_TOKEN in Secret xxx/xxx-token
  Normal   Pulled     4m26s (x119 over 29m)  kubelet            Container image "df3.azurecr.io/xxx-engine:23.6.0-123.gf12345" already present on machine
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a reference to a key from a k8s secret, but the key doesn't exist in the secret.

Go to the secret `xxx/xxx-token` and add there the key `XXX_TOKEN` with a value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it was the same issue for you, but i had this problem also when doing automated deployments from Azure DevOps using a predefined yaml pipeline. I set the job to use a windows image which seemed to cause the pods to get this error, when I swotch the vmImage to Ubuntu-latest it solved my issue and the pods successfully deployed.